# Is Apache web server required for jenkins installation

Tags: apache, tomcat, jenkins

Is it necessary for jenkins, that we need to install apache web server even if we have tomcat installed. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From - https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/

> Jenkins is typically run as a standalone application in its own process with the built-in Java servlet container/application server (Jetty).
>
> Jenkins can also be run as a servlet in different Java servlet containers such as Apache Tomcat or GlassFish.

So you can use Jenkins "as-is" or use with Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

No. Apache Tomcat can handle HTTP and HTTPS requests on its own as configured in server.xml

Default HTTP Port is 8080 -> default local URL: http://localhost:8080/jenkins

Default HTTPS Port is 8443 -> default local URL: https://localhost:8443/jenkins